# Height, position of budgies cage at desk

Tags: birds, cage

I have budgies and I learned now that cage should be at eye level of walking person. But what about sitting person?

Budgies cage is on my desk. The desk table is two meters long and about one meter deep. The cage currently is 80cm x 40cm x 40cm and is aligned along the desk length, sitting at the right back corner.

My eyes are at the same level as the top of the cage. When I stand up, my eyes level is significantly higher. Would you suggest to move it up, leaving some desk space below the cage where I can do my homework while the cage is on four long legs, or to get a cage that is two times higher and it still uses this desk space?

i.e.

**Current position:**

My desk space with a monitor that is about 50cm high. || Bird cage (about 80cm high).

*Concerns:*

.- bird cage possibly too small,

.- my desk space possibly too small,

.- unused space at the top.

**Version 1 of new position:**

My desk space with a monitor that is about 50cm high. || Bird cage (about 160cm high).

*In this case*

.+ birds can choose to be at eye level of either sitting or standing human.

.+ The birds cage is doubled in height, but

.- still short.

**Version 2 of new position:**

*Level 2: *Nothing || Bird cage (about 80cm high) is elevated 80cm above desk level, there is possibly space for another person to work.

*Level 1: *My doubled desk space.

.? In this case the birds are a bit above eye level at all times when I sit, but at eye level of walking people. (Good or bad?)

.+ I get my desk space increased twofold.

**Version 3 of new position:**

*level 2:* Bird cage (>120cm long, >120cm high, 40cm deep - elevated above doubled desk space - on four long legs.

*level 1: *My doubled desk space.

*In this case*

.? Birds are a bit above eye level at all times when I sit, but at eye level of walking people. (Good or bad?)

.+  I get my desk space increased twofold.

.+ The cage is also significantly larger and longer.

.+ Space above is used more effectively.

...

I have a screen at my desk, but I don't play music or videos on it. The TV is in another area in the house.

- Is it important for birds to be at eye level of sitting people or walking people or both?
- Do they need a longer or higher cage? What is more important? They might start to breed soon.

Please help and give me advice about this. How did this work out for you?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could add a last paragraph "long to short" because it is a wall of text to work through, this fear most people to read and answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I could not choose which of your options is the best for your circumstances.

First: the size for one pair should be minimum 45cm x 80cm at the ground. This is only suitable if they have 4 hours free flying in the room per day! If you think about breeding and do not give all little ones away, then you should include this in the new cage size early.

The rules of thumb are this:  The ground as near at a square as possible (no long thin ground) and width is more important than high because they fly more horizontally than vertically (but the birds are thankfully for each centimeter more in high) .

This point about the eye level: if the birds are in nature, they would sit in trees and bushes in a high minimum the eye level of humans. If they sit nearer to the ground they feel not secure. It is inside their mind, they could not change it. They feel vulnerable near the ground, for example by cats.

If you like to give them the possibility to get in contact with you, sitting at the desk, you should have a cage with place to sit (for the birds) at your sitting high and place to sit at the eye level of a standing person. So you let your birds choose if they feel fine at the one or the other place. This could change with daytime or daily feelings of them.

If you have not enough space on your desk you could build some board to put the cage on it (beside the desk, or on the desk as storage).